# Error while Changing the image of the button from an image to another when clicked on the button

Tags: ios, swift, xcode9.2, swift4.2

Here is my code :

```
@IBAction func moreClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if sender.currentImage == #imageLiteral(resourceName: "more_off"){
        sender.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "more_on"), for: .normal)
    }
    else
    {
        sender.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "more_off"), for: .normal)
    }

}
```

I am getting this error:

> 2018-09-05 11:03:28.708661+0530 musicPlayer[25450:590989]
>   -[musicPlayer.SecondViewController more:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc1d4606d00
>
> 2018-09-05 11:03:28.715659+0530 musicPlayer[25450:590989] ***
>   Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[musicPlayer.SecondViewController more:]: unrecognized selector sent
>   to instance 0x7fc1d4606d00'
>   *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001087ea1e6 **exceptionPreprocess + 294  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x0000000107a36031 objc_exception_throw + 48  2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x000000010886b784 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] +
>   132   3   UIKit                               0x0000000108e956db
>   -[UIResponder doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 295    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010876c898 ___forwarding_** + 1432  5   CoreFoundation
>   0x000000010876c278 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120    6   UIKit
>   0x0000000108c683e8 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
>     7   UIKit                               0x0000000108de37a4
>   -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67     8   UIKit                               0x0000000108de3ac1 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 450
>     9   UIKit                               0x0000000108de2a09
>   -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 580    10  UIKit                               0x0000000108cdd0bf -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2729     11  UIKit
>   0x0000000108cde7c1 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4086  12  UIKit
>   0x0000000108c82310 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 352  13  UIKit
>   0x00000001095c36af **dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 2796
>     14  UIKit                               0x00000001095c62c4
>   __handleEventQueueInternal + 5949     15  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010878cbb1
>   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17   16  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001087714af
>   __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 271   17  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108770a6f __CFRunLoopRun + 1263    18  CoreFoundation
>   0x000000010877030b CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 635     19  GraphicsServices
>   0x000000010ff76a73 GSEventRunModal + 62   20  UIKit
>   0x0000000108c67057 UIApplicationMain + 159    21  musicPlayer
>   0x000000010711cc27 main + 55  22  libdyld.dylib
>   0x000000010cd4f955 start + 1 ) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with
>   uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: your code is working perfect.

Comment: Your IBActions are probably connected wrongly. Disconnect the action and connect it again. Or are you doing it programmatically with `addTarget`?

Comment: I deleted the previous connection and connected it again. It works now, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 2018-09-05 11:03:28.708661+0530 musicPlayer[25450:590989]
>   -[musicPlayer.SecondViewController more:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc1d4606d00

The above message means that `SecondViewController` expects to have method called `more:` but when the action is triggered and instance from this class tries to find the `more:` method, it does not recognise such method and the application crashes.

What I think has happened here is: you have dragged action from your Xib/Storyboard to your VC class and named it `more:`. After this you have renamed it manually (not Refactor > Rename) to `moreClicked:`. This way the IBAction of the `SecondViewController` still points to method that is called `more:`, however your class does not have such method anymore.

So basically, you need to remove the already existing reference of the IBAction from your xib/storyboard and reconnect it with the new method: `moreClicked:`, and all should be working.